# How can a make a photo respond to a mouse click?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, photo

Hey I have a few photos that I played around with using Tkinter and I'm wondering if there is a way I could make my respond to a mouse click? In other words, I'm looking to create a program where I click on a photo on a canvas and have it up open an .xml file on my computer.

code noob here. Appreciate all input to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag the image with a unique string, then use `tag_bind` to register a handler for the click event.

```
from Tkinter import *

def image_clicked(event):
    print "an image on the canvas was clicked!"
    print "now opening xml file..."
    #todo: open xml file here

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle([0,0,100,100], fill="blue", tag="opens_xml")
canvas.tag_bind("opens_xml", "<1>", image_clicked)

root.mainloop()
```

In the above example, `image_clicked` is only called when the blue rectangle is clicked.